# Programmatically created form with name conflict

Tags: forms, vba, excel

I'm creating in Excel VBA a form using code. The following code snippet presents a problem in which the form is somehow created with the name already correctly set and then afterwards, in the only place where I set the said variable, it raises an issue saying that there is a form with that name (the variable in case).

Here is my code:

```
Dim frmName As String
frmName = "frm_" & Replace(CStr(Nome_do_formulario), " ", "")
Set myForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)

With myForm
    .Properties("Caption") = Nome_do_formulario
    .Properties("Width") = 300
    .Properties("Height") = 270
    .Properties("Name") = frmName
End With
```

To be clear, the error is that when it reaches the line:

```
Set myForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)
```

Somehow it already creates a form with name that's set after at the `with` statement:

```
  With myForm
        .Properties("Caption") = Nome_do_formulario
        .Properties("Width") = 300
        .Properties("Height") = 270
        .Properties("Name") = frmName '<- HERE
    End With
```

And then, when it tries to run the `with` statement it breaks and says that a form with that name already exists.

The whole thing is ran at another module as:

```
Public Sub Main()

       Dim ac As autoCrud
       Set ac = New autoCrud
       ac.CreateCRUDView     

End Sub
```

The form creation happens inside the `ac.CreateCRUDView`.

How is it pulling the name variable before it's set and then trying to use it to make another form with the same name?

Comment: What is `Nome_do_formulario`?

Comment: it's just the readable name of the form set to a constant

Comment: When you run the script on a new sheet, does it run once at all? Or only after you've run it does it give you the error?  And to be clear, the error is that it's saying the name (.Properties("Name") = frmName) is saying that there's a form already with that name?

Comment: I've explained better now.

Answer (score 1):

VBE suffers heavily corruption when it is about UserForms collection in a VBA Project.
Even if you remove explicitly a UserForm from your project, you might get errors creating programatically (and sometimes in the normal way) another with the same name.

Try using this approach:

```
Dim frmName As String
Dim myForm As VBComponent

frmName = "frm_" & Replace(CStr(Nome_do_formulario), " ", "")
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm).Name = frmName
Set myForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(frmName)

With myForm
    .Properties("Caption") = Nome_do_formulario
    .Properties("Width") = 300
    .Properties("Height") = 270
End With
```

Remember, if you delete the newly created userform and run this code with the same `Nome_do_formulário` value, you'll get an error.

Comment: This code is actually inside a function of a class and this function is called upon an instance inside a Main sub...

Comment: You can just replace `Sub Main()` for `Function CreateForm(Nome_do_formulario)`, can't you?

Comment: It gets an "execution time error 50135: the method Name from the object _VBComponent has failed"

Comment: If you try using an "inedit" name for variable Nome_do_formulario you still get the error? If yes, I have no idea what might have been happening.