# Why am I getting a Path/File Access error trying to programatically name userform?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am using a userform to create ANOTHER userform based on variable inputs.  When I create the userform I want to give it a name relevant to the information from which the new form is being created.  I understand that I cannot have 2 forms with the same name but what confuses me is that I can't give a form a name that previously belonged to another form that has since been deleted without exporting it.  Even more peculiar, if I close excel and reopen it I can create the userform with the name I want.

So basically what I'm thinking is that there is some sort of temporary location that I need to clear before I try to recreate the "deleted" form.

Things to keep in mind:

- The error I'm getting is a "Path/File Access" error
- The userform can be created if excel is closed and then reopened
- The main userform lives in the Personal.xlsb file and so does the new form that's created, however I would like to eventually start writing the new userform to it's own regular .xlsm workbook (but that is not what this question about)

Here's my code:

```
Sub MakeForm()
    'make the vba window invisible, i think this is the actual tryout spec form
    Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
    'add and set InputForm

    Set InputForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)
    'set its properties
    With InputForm
        .Properties("Caption") = formTitle
        .Properties("Width") = 390
        .Properties("Height") = 377
        .Properties("Name") = formName
    End With
End Sub
```

`formTitle` and `formName` are both publicly declared strings that work just fine and have values (exactly the values I intend the to have) when the program goes into break mode after the runtime error occurs.

I hope this is enough information and I'm pretty new to Stack Overflow so I have like no rights and I'm kinda a VBA noob too so my apologies in advance.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you deleting the previous form in the same session? It may be that form is still "there" until something triggers a recompile in the VBProject.  You can always use an incrementing suffix for each new form is it continues to be an issue.  Doing this type of thing can be finicky/unpredictable.

Comment: Unless there's a command to flush the file buffers without closing the file, there's going to be a conflict.  Since closing the file and re-opening solves the problem, and since that's technically the most correct way to do something like this, then write a "re-open" method which does just that and call it whenever needed.

Comment: @TimWilliams what is a session and how is a recompile triggered?

Comment: @BillHileman what would be the best command to use to do that?  or just to flush the file buffers (unless that's a bad or dangerous idea)

Comment: As a rule, when I code my accounting application (VB 6) I write one method to open all files and another method to close all files.  That's all that either of those methods (subs) do.  I call the open during form load and close during form unload, but then if I need to close and re-open, I call the methods back-to-back, close, then open.  It's really just that simple.  It comes in handy because I might need to do a close and re-open if my client changes fiscal year, for example.  Just modularize your code to make it easier.

Comment: Buy "same session" I mean you have not closed and re-opened the workbook, or something else hasn't happened which would cause the VBProject to be reset (for example, an unhandled error).  Unless the VBProject gets reset the compiled version of the original form may still be present in your project, so adding a new form with the same name may cause a conflict (that part is my best guess...)

Comment: This is a known problem and there is no easy solution. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826168/programmatically-created-form-with-name-conflict. However there is a workaround: do not delete unneeded forms once you have created them, just hide them, and show them again when needed: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=228